# Using 'like' on 2 SQL columns combined

Tags: laravel

I currently have 2 columns in my table going by the name of **uploadDate** and **uploadTime**. I have a clause like this:

```
->orWhere('uploadDate', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%')
->orWhere('uploadTime', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%');
```

The problem is that if **$request->search = yyyy-mm-dd, hh:mm:ss**, my web app is not able to get any results since uploadDate and uploadTime are seperate columns on the DB. Does anyone have a way of creating a **orWhere** statement that concatinates both **uploadDate** and **uploadTime**?

I know this can be easily achieved by just creating a single column in the DB that merges both columns but I'm just looking for an easier way out at this point, hahaha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `like` or `orWhere()` here if you want to find records by exact date and time.

```
->where('uploadDate', str_before($request->search, ','))
->where('uploadTime', str_after($request->search, ', '))
```

If you have other `where()` or `orWhere()` clauses in the query, you can do this:

```
->where([
    'uploadDate', '=', str_before($request->search, ','),
    'uploadTime', '=', str_after($request->search, ', ')
])
```

Comment: I use **like** because this function is mainly to be used as a search. Is there a better way to doing this instead of using **like**?

Comment: @RaySmith if you want to search by full datetime like `yyyy-mm-dd, hh:mm:ss`, you shouldn't use like. Use `like` instead of `=` only if `$request->search` can contain something like `1998` and you want to get all records from the year 1998.